# How to add an horizontal scrollbar to a table with unfixed width?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-tables

I want to add an horizontal scrollbar to a table. However the user can add row to the table, so its width must change. A row is 100px width so with 10 rows, my table have a width of 1000px but the div who contain the table is only 800px width. I want if the table's width is bigger than the div's width an horizontal scrollbar in the table.

```
<div style="width:800px;overflow:auto;">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by adding `overflow-x:scroll` and there will always be a scrollbar on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I put on the div container:

```
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

and on both the div and the table:

```
width: -moz-available;
width: -webkit-fill-available;
```

simplified html:

```
<div class="container">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

I have a few tables on the same page, one of which would be narrower than full width so it is stretched. Another is wider so it's displayed to container's full width and has a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: fill-available is now called "stretch"

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow: auto;` to your div and give your table a fixed width + `overflow-x: scroll;`.

Have a look:

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 800px;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There are 2 scrollbars (1 for table and 1 for the entire content). You need to use 2 different scrollbars to rewind the table completely.